# Validate IAM User Credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I research for some methods in **AmazonIdentityManagement** but don't found nothing util to implement my task. It is possible somehow to validate given *username* and *password* with existent users in IAM ?

Test case:

1. User inserts in form "username", "password"
2. Backend find for valid user-pass in IAM Users
3. Depends on result redirect to app / show error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Username & Password assigned to an IAM User can only be used to login to the AWS Management Console.

All programmatic access (API calls) to AWS requires an Access Key and Secret Key.

If your desire is to maintain a **database of application users** so that they can be validated for access to your own web application, you should manage users within [Amazon Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html) rather than AWS IAM.